# Why is my EditText Resource evaluating to null in my android app?

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

So I have a dialogue box that is means to accept a username and password, But when I try to get the Username and Password from the `EditText` object, I can't seem to actually get the `EditText` Object from resources, my code looks like this.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int ID){
     LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
     final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.login_dialogue, null);
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setTitle("Login:")
         .setView(textEntryView)
         .setPositiveButton("login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                 /* Problem occurs below */
                 View aView = findViewById(R.id.login_dialogue_username);
                 String username = ((EditText) aView).getText().toString();
                 String password = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_dialogue_password)).getText().toString();
                 boolean success = attemptLogin(username, password);
             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                 /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
             }
         })
         .create();
 }
```

So when I step through in debug, the `aView` variable is null, but I can't see why. The resource is in my `R` file and it is colored blue in eclipse, indicating that it is matching to the name to the R file. Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the layout of the Activity. Try using

```
textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.login_dialogue_username);
```

instead.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, Thanks! So `findViwById()` is actually getting called on the Activity running underneath the dialog, so it isn't looking in the right place?

Comment: Correct, and you want to find the view inside the dialog, so you use the inflated `View` for the dialog layout.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that the `EditText` your interested in (`R.id.login_dialogue_username`) is inside the layout hierarchy inflated from `R.layout.login_dialogue`, and not the content view of the overall Activity.

If so, you need to use `textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.login_dialogue_username)` to find the view you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and recompile your project ?

It happened to me sometimes, and it seems that under certain conditions, Android messes up with ids in the R class. cleaning and recompiling your project will regenerate the R class.